# Android inflating layout XML file created runtime

Tags: java, android, xml, user-interface, layout-inflater

I plan to create XML layouts of my UI runtime (not as usual R.layout.* files), saving them to temp storage (either in filesystem or in SQLite).

Reading docs I have found confusing statement to `public View inflate (XmlPullParser parser, ViewGroup root)`:

> Important   For performance reasons, view inflation relies heavily on
>   pre-processing of XML files that is done at build time. Therefore, it
>   is not currently possible to use LayoutInflater with an XmlPullParser
>   over a plain XML file at runtime.

Does someone know any way to resolve mentioned limitation? Probably use another View inflating procedure or smth similar/unparallel?

Comment: You could implement a do-it-yourself solution where you build the UI at runtime using your own config files.

Comment: I got annoyed enough to write my own library for this. The code is ugly and the performance terrible at the moment, but it's working well for my project: https://github.com/nickwah/DynamicLayoutInflator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That'll require writing down your own Layout Inflater, that can read XML on disk and build a layout out of it. You can traverse through the tag hierarchy, create and add views according to attributes of each tag etc. But it will be very slow as compared to default Android implementation.

Comment: OK, in reality I have already implemented my own inflater. I just thought that I could be using built-in one.